# Custom Password Validation in Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, password-protection

I'm trying to add custom password validation to a password field. The password has to have a minimum of 8 characters and meet at least two of the criteria below but does not have to meet all four:

- Has numbers
- Has lowercase letters
- Has uppercase letters
- Has special characters

I've got part of the validation working but am having an issue where if the password is 8+ characters long but does not meet at least two of the criteria above, the error message will **not** show. The error regarding the characters will only display if the password is less than 8 characters.

I've done a search across SO and haven't had success implementing answers to similar questions. I suspect the issue I'm having has to do with my custom validation function not being associated with the password in ngModel.

The Question: How can I get the error message to show on the form field when the password is 8+ characters long but does NOT meet the character requirements above?

Here's the associated code.

From **user-form.html**:

```
 <mat-form-field *ngIf="newPassword" fxFlex="100%">
  <input matInput #password="ngModel" placeholder="Password" type="password" autocomplete="password"
         [(ngModel)]="model.password" name="password" minlength="8" (keyup)="validatePassword(model.password)" required>
  <mat-error *ngIf="invalidPassword">
    Password must contain at least two of the following: numbers, lowercase letters, uppercase letters, or special characters.
  </mat-error>
  <mat-error *ngIf="password.invalid && (password.dirty || password.touched)">
    <div *ngIf="password.errors.required">
      Password is required
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="password.errors.minlength">
      Password must be at least 8 characters
    </div>
  </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

From **user-form.component.ts**:

```
export class UserFormComponent implements OnInit {


  @Input()
  user: User;

  public model: any;
  public invalidPassword: boolean;


  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.model = this.user;
  }


  passwordFails(checks: boolean[]): boolean {
     let counter = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < checks.length; i++) {
      if (checks[i]) {
        counter += 1;
      }
    }
    return counter < 2;
 }


  validatePassword(password: string) {
    let hasLower = false;
    let hasUpper = false;
    let hasNum = false;
    let hasSpecial = false;

    const lowercaseRegex = new RegExp("(?=.*[a-z])");// has at least one lower case letter
    if (lowercaseRegex.test(password)) {
      hasLower = true;
    }

    const uppercaseRegex = new RegExp("(?=.*[A-Z])"); //has at least one upper case letter
    if (uppercaseRegex.test(password)) {
      hasUpper = true;
    }

    const numRegex = new RegExp("(?=.*\\d)"); // has at least one number
    if (numRegex.test(password)) {
      hasNum = true;
    }

    const specialcharRegex = new RegExp("[!@#$%^&*(),.?\":{}|<>]");
    if (specialcharRegex.test(password)) {
      hasSpecial = true;
    }

    this.invalidPassword = this.passwordFails([hasLower, hasUpper, hasNum, hasSpecial]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played around with this further to see if I could figure out how to use the Validators in Angular. I was finally able to do that with these updates:

Create **password-validator.directive.ts**:

```
import { Directive, forwardRef, Attribute} from "@angular/core";
import { Validator, AbstractControl, NG_VALIDATORS} from "@angular/forms";

@Directive({
  selector: '[validatePassword]',
  providers: [
    { provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: forwardRef(() => PasswordValidator), multi: true}
  ]
})

export class PasswordValidator implements Validator {
  constructor (
    @Attribute('validatePassword')
    public invalidPassword: boolean
  ) {}

  validate(ctrl: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} {
    let password = ctrl.value;

    let hasLower = false;
    let hasUpper = false;
    let hasNum = false;
    let hasSpecial = false;

    const lowercaseRegex = new RegExp("(?=.*[a-z])");// has at least one lower case letter
    if (lowercaseRegex.test(password)) {
      hasLower = true;
    }

    const uppercaseRegex = new RegExp("(?=.*[A-Z])"); //has at least one upper case letter
    if (uppercaseRegex.test(password)) {
      hasUpper = true;
    }

    const numRegex = new RegExp("(?=.*\\d)"); // has at least one number
    if (numRegex.test(password)) {
      hasNum = true;
    }

    const specialcharRegex = new RegExp("[!@#$%^&*(),.?\":{}|<>]");
    if (specialcharRegex.test(password)) {
      hasSpecial = true;
    }

    let counter = 0;
    let checks = [hasLower, hasUpper, hasNum, hasSpecial];
    for (let i = 0; i < checks.length; i++) {
      if (checks[i]) {
        counter += 1;
      }
    }

    if (counter < 2) {
      return { invalidPassword: true }
    } else {
      return null;
    }



  }

}
```

Update in **user-form.component.html**:

```
<mat-form-field *ngIf="newPassword" fxFlex="100%">
  <input matInput #password="ngModel" placeholder="Password" type="password" autocomplete="password"
         [(ngModel)]="model.password" name="password" minlength="8" validatePassword="password" required>
  <mat-error *ngIf="password.invalid && (password.dirty || password.touched)">
    <div *ngIf="password.errors.invalidPassword">
      Password must have two of the four: lowercase letters, uppercase letters, numbers, and special characters
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="password.errors.required">
      Password is required
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="password.errors.minlength">
      Password must be at least 8 characters
    </div>
  </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Update in **user-form.module.ts**:

```
import {PasswordValidator} from "../password-validator.directive"; //imported to modules

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    //some modules
  ],
  declarations: [
    // some modules
    PasswordValidator // added this to declarations
  ],
  exports: [
    // stuff
  ],
  providers: [
    //stuff
  ]
})
export class UserFormModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `boolean` values to `passwordFails` function

```
this.invalidPassword = this.passwordFails([hasLower, hasUpper, hasNum, hasSpecial]);
```

Change your function to below, which would return true if the password fails in one of the criteria.

```
passwordFails(checks: boolean[]): boolean {
   return checks.filter((x)=> typeof x === 'boolean' && x === true).length > 2
}
```

And in the dom you can add another condition to check for invalidPassword

```
 <mat-form-field *ngIf="newPassword" fxFlex="100%">
  <input matInput #password="ngModel" placeholder="Password" type="password" autocomplete="password"
         [(ngModel)]="model.password" name="password" minlength="8" (keyup)="validatePassword(model.password)" required>
  <mat-error *ngIf="invalidPassword">
    Password must contain at least two of the following: numbers, lowercase letters, uppercase letters, or special characters.
  </mat-error>
  <mat-error *ngIf="password.invalid && (password.dirty || password.touched)">
    <div *ngIf="password.errors.required">
      Password is required
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="password.errors.minlength">
      Password must be at least 8 characters
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="!invalidPassword">
      Password must meet the following criteria.
    </div>
  </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: I tried updating the passwordFails function but I don't think that meets my criteria - the password only has to meet two of the character criteria, not all of them. As it is with the updated version, I think it's only checking if one of the criteria is met.
For example, when I have an empty password field, it displays the criteria error.
 But then when I type in 1, that error message goes away.

Comment: @vox: check my updated edit and let me know if it was helpful.

Comment: Ok cool, that ended up working when I switched > 2 to be > 1. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/custom-password-validation-in-angular-5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

**Component.html**

```
<div class="error-text" *ngIf="myForms.get('password').hasError('passwordStrength')">
    {{myForms.get('password').errors['passwordStrength']}}
</div>
```

**Component.ts**

```
this.myForms = fb.group({
      password: [null, Validators.compose([
        Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8), PasswordStrengthValidator])]
});
```

**password-strength.validators.ts**

```
import { AbstractControl, ValidationErrors } from "@angular/forms"

export const PasswordStrengthValidator = function (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {


let value: string = control.value || '';
  let msg="";
  if (!value) {
    return null
  }

  let upperCaseCharacters = /[A-Z]+/g;
  let lowerCaseCharacters = /[a-z]+/g;
  let numberCharacters = /[0-9]+/g;
  let specialCharacters = /[!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]+/;
  if (upperCaseCharacters.test(value) === false || lowerCaseCharacters.test(value) === false || numberCharacters.test(value) === false || specialCharacters.test(value) === false) {
return {
  passwordStrength: 'Password must contain at least two of the following: numbers, lowercase letters, uppercase letters, or special characters.'
}
```

}

```
}
```